# Finding the probability of choosing a number from interval [-2,2] that makes the solution of an equation imaginary

Tags: probability, algebra-precalculus

I found this question from an old math questionnaire.

Two numbers p and q are both chosen randomly (and independent of each other) from the interval [-2,2]. Find the probability that $$4x^2+4px+1-q^2=0$$ has imaginary roots.

I tried manipulating the equation by completing the square and solving for x. I assumed that the given interval only contains integral elements. I obtained a discriminant of $$q^2-1$$ and thus I concluded that only 5 elements (q is 0 and p is -2,-1,0,1,2) that can make the root imaginary out of 25 elements. So my probability is 5/25 or 1/5.

However, when I looked at the answer at the back of the questionnaire, it answered pi/16. Can anyone help me in pointing out where I go wrong?

Comment: You assumed that $q$ and $p$ must be integers, which is not implied in the question.

Comment: The roots can only be *imaginary* if $p = 0$, so the probability of imaginary roots is $0$. This question is about the probability that the roots are complex (or equivalently, not real).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The discriminant is
$$ 16p^2-16(1-q^2)=16(p^2+q^2-1) $$
so in order for the quadratic to have imaginary roots, we must have $p^2+q^2<1$.

Asssuming that $p$ and $q$ are real numbers chosen independently and uniformly at random from $[-2,2]$, the desired probability is then the area of the unit disk divided by the area of the square $[-2,2]\times[-2,2]$, i.e. $\frac{\pi}{16}$.